# Как правильно произнести "в 600 пунктах"? Порядок слов: "более чем в" или "в более чем"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные, порядок-слов

Вы можете получить подарок более чем в 600 пунктах по всему миру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас правильно. Именно такой порядок ("более чем в ...") является безусловно нормативным и до недавнего времени - единственно возможным.

Иное ("в более чем") раньше не признавалось вовсе, сейчас принимается максимум как разговорный вариант - видимо, просто, бороться стало бесполезно, когда все говорят именно так.

Вот навскидку, что нашлось. Там обсуждение и последний "официальный" ответ "Грамоты".
http://forum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=6237

Answer (score 0):

**Вы можете получить подарок более чем в 600 (шестистах) пунктах по всему миру.**

Числительное *шестьсот* в предложним падеже принимает форму *шестиста́х*. (См. [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82))